# Wait for a promise to be resolved before continuing with function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, html2canvas

I know this has been asked many times, but the async/promise concept is very obscure to me!
I am trying to take a screenshot using **html2canvas** and once the (or multiple) screenshots are generated, continue with the function and send it through a POST request.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
async function take_screenshot1() {
    const screenshotTarget = document.body;
    const screenshot1 = html2canvas(screenshotTarget).then((canvas) => {
    const screenshot1 = canvas.toDataURL();
    return screenshot1
});
    return screenshot1
}

var screenshot1 = take_screenshot1()
```

And

```
async function take_screenshot() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const screenshotTarget = document.body;
        var result = html2canvas(screenshotTarget).then((canvas) => {
    const screenshot1 = canvas.toDataURL();
});
        resolve(result);
      }, 300);
  });
}

  var screenshot = await take_screenshot();
  console.log(`After await: ${screenshot}`);
  console.log("I expect to be after the values");
```

If someone could give me some advice about where I get things wrong, I would appreciate it!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: The point of using `async` functions is to _not_ use `.then()` callbacks.

Comment: Are you taking each shot and then posting it, or are you grouping the shots and then posting them all at once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your grouping your data but this is a simple example. `async` functions return a promise so you need to await them too.

```js
const { body } = document;

async function takeScreenshot() {
  const screenshot = await html2canvas(body);
  return screenshot.toDataURL();
}

async function main() {
  const canvas = await takeScreenshot();
  body.appendChild(canvas);
}

main();
```